# Gaussian blur filter weight calculation formula is not clear

Tags: functions

[Here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-RenderTexture_Plus_Blur) you can see Gaussian blur filter weight calculation formula:

```
void TextureBlur::calculateGaussianWeights(const int points, float* weights)
{
    float dx = 1.0f/float(points-1);
    float sigma = 1.0f/3.0f;
    float norm = 1.0f/(sqrtf(2.0f*M_PI)*sigma*points);
    float divsigma2 = 0.5f/(sigma*sigma);
    weights[0] = 1.0f;
    for (int i = 1; i < points; i++)
    {
        float x = float(i)*dx;
        weights[i] = norm*expf(-x*x*divsigma2);
        weights[0] -= 2.0f*weights[i];
    }
}
```

Why on line `float norm = ...` we have `*points`? Why we should divide the norm on point count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaussian weights are being calculated like `G(x) * dx` and I think `norm` should be defined as:

```
`float norm = 1.0f/(sqrtf(2.0f*M_PI)*sigma);` // without `*points`
```

and also the weights formula should should change to

```
`weights[i] = norm*expf(-x*x*divsigma2)*dx;`
```

which will bring us to almost the same thing expect for weight not we divide not to `points` but to `points - 1`.